# Blocking all about.com websites (*.about.com) from my Google search results

Tags: google-search, spam-prevention

I regularly block websites from my Google search results. I've had no trouble with this Google feature, with the notable exception of `about.com`. This website uses a million subdomains, making it hard to block all of them. Every time an `about.com` site shows up in my results, I have to manually block it.

I've tried blocking `*.about.com`, like so:
[image]

but it hasn't worked.

Any way I can block `[anything].about.com` from my search results?

Answer (score 1):

What about

blablabla -site:about.com

If you wanna know more about "Google operators", take a look at http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators_reference.html and/or http://www.googleguide.com

I often use this and it can be extremely helpful sometimes!

Edit:
You don't need to block [anything].about.com, just about.com because [anything].about.com is a sub domain to about.com. The minus sign is used for negation and "site:".. I think you understand...

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP wants to block all sub domains of about.com.  You are simply telling him not to. Either edit your post to answer the question or remove it. Thank you.

Comment: @Barry Ehh.. I thought I said that blocking the whole site is "block the site with all it's subdomains". Have you tried "blablabla -site:about.com"? Is it something wrong with it? No? Then, please do something about your negative vote or tell me what's wrong with my answer. Sorry if I misunderstood something.

Comment: This is the method I use successfully. As outlined here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30198/block-sites-from-appearing-in-bing-search-results/61166#61166

Answer (score 1):

`search terms -site:.about.com` blocks subdomains of about.com.  You probably need to remove the `*` from your preferences because there's no domain with `*` in its name.

Answer (score 1):

This answer might be a little overdue - however, blocking `http://about.com` should work.