# Block sites from appearing in Bing Search results

Tags: bing

Is there a way to tell Bing that I never want results from a certain domain?

Comment: Seems like this would be an excellent extension/add-on.

Comment: Excellent extension, as requested: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/160190/290085

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I add -site:blockeddomain.com after my search items.

`how to paint barn -site:ehow.com -site:experts-exchange.com -site:ebay.com -site:dotnetspark.com -site:go4sharepoint.com -site:wikihow.com -site:howstuffworks.com`

In this example I have added my current ignore list. To make it easy for day-to-day use, I use a text expander to enter all the domains that annoy me. In my text expander I make all instances of "---" show up as "-site:ehow.com -site:experts-exchange.com -site:ebay.com -site:dotnetspark.com -site:go4sharepoint.com -site:wikihow.com -site:howstuffworks.com". I use the text expanding feature of [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) as I already use that program for several other automation tasks.

This works for [Bing](http://www.bing.com) and [Google](http://www.google.com). I used just -blockeddomain.com for Google successfully, but multiple domains this way broke [Bing](http://www.bing.com). Whereas with the -site: both search engines seem to behave appropriately.

It is not perfect, but it saves me time. Google used to let you block pages on a blacklist, but discontinued that service. We need to remember that in the search world, we are the product and

Or in Chrome modify your default search settings. Example: after the arrow insert `%20-site:ehow.com` to always append `-site:ehow.com` to your searches.

[image: google chrome search settings]

Comment: For the record, as of Nov 2021, the suggestion to exclude websites via Chrome (or Edge) by editing the "URL" part of the given browser's "Manage Search Engine" settings, cannot be performed. You can see the URL, but cannot edit it. I do not know whether there's a developer mode or flag to enable such.

Answer (score 3):

To hide results of any kind just use the — (minus, dash, etc.) operator.

Examples:

```
New York -yankees
```

The above will display results for 'New York' but exclude the 'yankees' keyword.

```
Disney Characters -disney.go.com
```

The above will display results for 'Disney Characters' while also removing results that have the 'disney.go.com' domain name.

Comment: This is a nice work around, but I don't think the OP wants to add (eg.) `-expertsexchange.com` to every query.  The functionality should be comparable to http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/1397, that is, when the OP is logged into Bing, there should be a setting that can be toggled for every query to remove a blacklist of sites.

Comment: +1 but yes, Keven Vermeer is correct (about a site in particular too!).

Comment: I see now that he said 'never' show them....hmmmm....good question.

Answer (score 3):

If you use uBlock Origin, you can add the filter:

```
bing.com##.b_algo:has(h2>a[href*="example.com"])
```

(Replacing `example.com` with a website's URL, or part of it.)

If you also want to filter out links from the "Explore later" section, try adding:

```
bing.com##.pageRecoContainer>table>tbody>tr:has(a[href*="example.com"])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your default search engine. It's easy to do this on any browser by relying on Mycroft's search engine form: http://mycroftproject.com/submitos.html

1. Find the search engine you want to modify on Mycroft (preferably for search the website URL).
2. Find the one you want to use in the results (probably under category "Major Engines") and hover its name to view an ID.
3. Fill in this ID in the form at the URL above and click "Load".
4. Modify this form how you see fit (probably by adding `+-site:bing.com` with the plus representing a space in URLs). You may need to change the name so that it doesn't conflict with already installed engines.
5. Click "Generate Plugin" and then "Test Plugin". Clicking "Test Plugin" will call the function [`window.external.AddSearchProvider`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sidebar/Adding_search_engines_from_Web_pages) off of a URL that generates your search plugin so you can install it. There is no need to click "Submit Plugin".

I've also recreated the form on jsfiddle with as few changes as possible. However it still relies on up to two GET requests from Mycroft. The benefit of this version is that it includes templates for Bing and Google so you can easily modify these without finding their ID: https://jsfiddle.net/dvd2fh8n/

Answer (score 0):

The [uBlacklist browser extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublacklist/pncfbmialoiaghdehhbnbhkkgmjanfhe?hl=en) works with bing.

[image: Screenshot of bing search results with site blocking options via uBlacklist]